# How do I pivot a dataset in R?

Tags: r, pivot

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
**Codes Year    Visits**
rhj384  2014    4,354
rhj384  2015    6,567
rhj384  2016    3,434
gnf203  2014    7,676
gnf203  2015    4,543
gnf203  2016    5,656
lpe021  2014    1,212
lpe021  2015    4,345
lpe021  2016    6,567
bng485  2014    7,787
bng485  2015    5,656
bng485  2016    6,767
```

I can pivot this data in excel so it looks like this: [image]

I want to do the exact same thing but in R. How do I do this?

I've managed to plot the data by doing plot(x,y) however, I've had no luck when it comes to grouping the Codes. How do I pivot in R?

Comment: Please give some example code and what library you are using, in ggplot2 it;s as simple as adding `color = Year` to the aesthetics

Comment: You don't need to pivot to do this. Assuming you've reformatted `Visits` from string to numeric without the commas, you can produce this plot with `library(ggplot2) ; ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Visits, color = Codes)) + geom_line()`.